# PHP TCPDF ACTUALIZACION 7.2.X

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

Tengo un sistema que genera PDF con TCPDF pero al parecer este ultimo no soporte PHP 7.4 ya que le cambie la version a 7.0 y me corre de maravilla:

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba_simple\pdf\html2pdf.class.php on line 1530

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba_simple\pdf\html2pdf.class.php on line 1531

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba_simple\pdf\html2pdf.class.php on line 1532

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba_simple\pdf\html2pdf.class.php on line 1533

Estas son las lineas de codigo en donde me genera el error,

```
        if ($inTL[0]<=0 || $inTL[1]<=0) $inTL = null;
        if ($inTR[0]<=0 || $inTR[1]<=0) $inTR = null;
        if ($inBR[0]<=0 || $inBR[1]<=0) $inBR = null;
        if ($inBL[0]<=0 || $inBL[1]<=0) $inBL = null;
```

Espero me puedan hechar una mano, saludos.

Comment: Necesitas actualizar html2pdf. https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/pull/551/commits/607e84732f810aaf41e0caafcc666e8b7fd4f870

Comment: juanrpozo, gracias por responder.
Actualice la lineas que me dejas en el link y ahora me bota en el siguiente error al parecer se soluciono pero ahora me bota un error en esta linea de codigo

    $this->SetFont($this->footer_font[0], $this->footer_font[1], $this->footer_font[2]);

Espero puedas hecharme una mano, gracias de antemano